# Android Listview with Custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-listview

I am having trouble setting the custom array adapter for my program. Here is some of the sample code below:

The xml activity_main:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TableLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:stretchColumns="1" >

                        <TableRow android:id="@+id/row1" >

                            <TextView android:text="@string/name" >
                            </TextView>

                            <EditText android:id="@+id/name" >
                            </EditText>
                        </TableRow>

                        <TableRow android:id="@+id/row2" >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                                android:text="@string/address" />

                            <EditText android:id="@+id/address" />
                        </TableRow>

                        <TableRow android:id="@+id/row3" >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                                android:text="@string/type" />

                            <RadioGroup android:id="@+id/group" >

                                <RadioButton
                                    android:id="@+id/takeout"
                                    android:text="@string/takeout" />

                                <RadioButton
                                    android:id="@+id/delivery"
                                    android:text="@string/delivery" />

                                <RadioButton
                                    android:id="@+id/sitdown"
                                    android:text="@string/sitdown" />
                            </RadioGroup>
                        </TableRow>

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/add"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="@string/addr" />
                    </TableLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/listview"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
                    </ListView>
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The xml for the activity_list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:padding="4px">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="4px"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/listName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/listAddress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="end"         
            android:text="TextView" />
    </LinearLayout>    
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the custom ArrayAdapter class:

```
 // adapter to populate the rows of the listview
    private class restaurantAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<restaurant>{
        public restaurantAdapter(){
            super(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, restList);
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

            View row = convertView;
            restaurantHolder holder = null;

            if(row == null){
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                // set the row of data to the specified xml formatting
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.actitivity_list, null);
                holder = new restaurantHolder(row);
                row.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                holder = (restaurantHolder)row.getTag();
            }

            holder.populateFrom(restList.get(position));

            return row;         
        }
    }



// creates a holder for the adapter
    private class restaurantHolder{
        private TextView rowName = null;
        private TextView addrName = null;
        private ImageView rowIcon = null;
        private View row = null;

        public restaurantHolder(View row){
            this.row = row;
        }

        public void populateFrom(restaurant r){

            getName().setText(r.getName());
            getAddress().setText(r.getAddress());

            if(r.getMealType().equals("Delivery")){
                getIcon().setImageResource(R.drawable.ball_yellow);
            }else if(r.getMealType().equals("Sit Down")){
                getIcon().setImageResource(R.drawable.ball_red);
            }else{
                getIcon().setImageResource(R.drawable.ball_green);
            }

        }

        private TextView getName(){
            if(rowName == null){
                rowName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.listName);
            }
            return rowName;
        }

        private TextView getAddress(){
            if(addrName == null){
                addrName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.listAddress);
            }
            return addrName;
        }

    private ImageView getIcon(){
    if(rowIcon == null){
            rowIcon = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.icon);
        }
        return rowIcon;
    }       
}
```

The program crashes as soon as the holder.populateFrom medthod is called in the arrayAdapter. I tried debugging it for a while a while but it just gives me an unhelpful null pointer exception. I feel like the adapter holder class is not connecting to the activity_list xml file but I unsure at this point. Any suggestion would be helpful.

I know its a lot of code but I think I just need a fresh set of eyes on it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: As far as I looked at your code, its a bit of messy. And you are creating custom adapter by extending ArrayAdapter but I will suggest you to extend **BaseAdapter** for custom adapter...that will be better. If you ask then I will suggest you some tutorial for that.

Answer (score 0):

You are inflating the wrong layout for your list rows. It should be:

```
  public restaurantAdapter(){
      super(MainActivity.this, R.layout.activity_list, restList);
  }
```

Instead of `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`. The `NullPointerException` occurs because there is no `View` with the id `listName` or `listAddress` in `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`.

Also, consider renaming the file to `list_item` or something else because it is not an activity but an item of the list view within the main activity.

Comment: It seems that the problem is that my program crashes whenever I access the second xml file. I just tried setting some random text with a button to the text view on the second xml file and my program crashed. Any thoughts on why this is happening?

Comment: Show the stacktrace